# Docker keeps creating folders with root permissions

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile for zookeeper

```
FROM zookeeper:3.7.0

ARG appuser
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash $appuser
RUN chown -R $appuser/conf /data /logs /datalog
USER $appuser
```

where I specify my own user with `docker build -t my/zookeeper:3.7.0 --build-arg appuser=myuser .`

However when I run it with the command

`docker run -u myuser -v /Products/zookeeper:/data my/zookeeper:3.7.0`

it fails with `/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 47: /data/myid: Permission denied` and I see that it is probably trying to create folders as `root` like:

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root       6 Jun 21 17:25 zookeeper`

`myuser` exists on the host and has necessary permissions. Why is not using what I provided and fails due to permissions?

Comment: It appears that the image you are using already supports the --user run arg natively judging by it's entrypoint. It uses gosu to set the zookeper user to the given uid that is specified and adjusts the owner of the directories above accordingly when the container is started. Which would explain your issue. [source](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/master/3.7.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L6)

Comment: if I go like that I get the error: docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file.

Comment: the user argument only allows you to set a username that is actually part of the image. But you can also set it to any user id that you like. If you want to run it with your current user for example you may use: `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`

Comment: Yes, but I define myuser inside the container and chown so I still don't understand why I get no permission error in the original case

Comment: @pat actually using $(id -u):$(id -g) instead of the name of the user works perfectly, so that was the problem I didn't expect that I thought they were the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude: The zookeper image is already capable of applying the correct permissions to the directories it is creating by using the native [--user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) argument of docker run.

It's important to know that if you provide a username, the user must already be present in the image. Specifying a user id and/or group id however works as intended.

Zookeper uses [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) to adjust the directory ownership in it's [entrypoint](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/master/3.7.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L7).

Here is an example how to run the image (on linux) while giving the current user the directory ownership of the directories it's creating:

`docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /Products/zookeeper:/data my/zookeeper:3.7.0`